# django template rendering error when template have comparison 'equal'

Tags: python, django, django-templates, jinja2

I got problem about template rendering in django.
It's show up when there is kind of integer comparison with '=='.

I have a view like ..

```
def mailtemplate_GetSchema(request, id=None):
  if id == None:
    svars = []
    this_var = {}
    this_var['s_id']=str(uuid4())
    this_var['varname'] = f"varname_{this_var['s_id']}"
    this_var['varlabel'] = f"varlabel_{this_var['s_id']}"
    this_var['vartype'] = f"vartype_{this_var['s_id']}"
    this_var['varformat'] = f"varformat_{this_var['_sid']}"
    this_var['varname_value'] = ''
    this_var['varlabel_value'] = ''
    this_var['vartype_value'] = 1
    this_var['varformat_value'] = ''
    svars.append(this_var)

    return render(request, 'mailtemplate_all.html', {'svars': svars})

  try :
    obj = MailTemplate.objects.get(pk=id)
    schema = obj.schema
    schema = json.loads(schema)
    # it's a list of dictionary
    vars = []
    for s in schema:
      this_var = {}
      this_var['field_id']=str(uuid4())
      this_var['varname'] = f"varname_{this_var['field_id']}"
      this_var['varlabel'] = f"varlabel_{this_var['field_id']}"
      this_var['vartype'] = f"vartype_{this_var['field_id']}"
      this_var['varformat'] = f"varformat_{this_var['field_id']}"
      this_var['varname_value'] = s.get('name','')
      this_var['varlabel_value'] = s.get('label','')
      this_var['vartype_value'] = s.get('type',1)
      this_var['varformat_value'] = s.get('format',None)
      if this_var['varformat_value'] == '':
        this_var['varformat_value']=False
      vars.append(this_var)

    print(f'VARS:{vars}')
    return render(request, 'mailtemplate_all.html', {'vars': vars})

  except MailTemplate.DoesNotExist:
    return HttpResponseNotFound()
```

the 'mailtemplate_all.html' is :

```
{% for v in vars%}
<div id={{ v.field_id }} class="divTableRow">
  <div class="divTableCell">
    <input type="text" name={{v.varname}} value={{ v.varname_value}} class="vTextField" maxlength="20" >
  </div>

  <div class="divTableCell">
    <input type="text" name={{v.varlabel}} value={{ v.varlabel_value}} class="vTextField" maxlength="20" >
  </div>

  <div class="divTableCell">
    <select name={{v.vartype}}>
      {% if v.vartype_value==1 %}
        <option value=1 selected>
      {% else %}
        <option value=1>
      {% endif %}
      Integer</option>

      {% if v.vartype_value==2 %}
        <option value=2 selected>
      {% else %}
        <option value=2>
      {% endif %}
      String</option>

      {% if v.vartype_value==3 %}
        <option value=3 selected>
      {% else %}
        <option value=3>
      {% endif %}
      Date</option>

    </select>
  </div>

  <div class="divTableCell">
    <input type="text" name={{v.varformat}} {% if v.varformat_value %}value={{v.varformat_value}}{% endif %}  class="vTextField" maxlength="20" >
  </div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

When the view called, I got error

```
[13/Jan/2023 08:23:12] "GET /static/admin/fonts/Roboto-Bold-webfont.woff HTTP/1.1" 200 86184
VARS:[{'field_id': 'ac9a3707-3906-4e75-9efd-514959056ddb', 'varname': 'varname_ac9a3707-3906-4e75-9efd-514959056ddb', 'varlabel': 'varlabel_ac9a3707-3906-4e75-9efd-514959056ddb', 'vartype': 'vartype_ac9a3707-3906-4e75-9efd-514959056ddb', 'varformat': 'varformat_ac9a3707-3906-4e75-9efd-514959056ddb', 'varname_value': 'kepada', 'varlabel_value': 'Kepada', 'vartype_value': 2, 'varformat_value': False}]
Internal Server Error: /mst/htmx/get_schema/2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/bino/.venv/htmx01/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/smartif.py", line 179, in translate_token
    op = OPERATORS[token]
KeyError: 'v.vartype_value==1'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/bino/.venv/htmx01/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/bino/.venv/htmx01/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 197, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/bino/Documents/dynform/htmx01/myapp/views.py", line 48, in mailtemplate_GetSchema
    return render(request, 'mailtemplate_all.html', {'vars': vars})
...
  File "/home/bino/.venv/htmx01/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/smartif.py", line 181, in translate_token
    return self.create_var(token)
  File "/home/bino/.venv/htmx01/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 889, in create_var
    return TemplateLiteral(self.template_parser.compile_filter(value), value)
  File "/home/bino/.venv/htmx01/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 600, in compile_filter
    return FilterExpression(token, self)
  File "/home/bino/.venv/htmx01/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 703, in __init__
    raise TemplateSyntaxError(
django.template.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: Could not parse the remainder: '==1' from 'v.vartype_value==1'
[13/Jan/2023 08:23:12] "GET /mst/htmx/get_schema/2 HTTP/1.1" 500 200297
Not Found: /favicon.ico
[13/Jan/2023 08:23:12] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 2212
```

So I take the 'vars' printed out from my views, and use it to test from python shell

```
(htmx01)  bino@corobalap  ~/Documents/dynform/htmx01  python3
Python 3.10.6 (main, Nov 14 2022, 16:10:14) [GCC 11.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from jinja2 import Template
>>> vars=[{'field_id': 'ac9a3707-3906-4e75-9efd-514959056ddb', 'varname': 'varname_ac9a3707-3906-4e75-9efd-514959056ddb', 'varlabel': 'varlabel_ac9a3707-3906-4e75-9efd-514959056ddb', 'vartype': 'vartype_ac9a3707-3906-4e75-9efd-514959056ddb', 'varformat': 'varformat_ac9a3707-3906-4e75-9efd-514959056ddb', 'varname_value': 'kepada', 'varlabel_value': 'Kepada', 'vartype_value': 2, 'varformat_value': False}]
>>> with open('myapp/templates/mailtemplate_all.html','r') as tfile:
...     template = Template(tfile.read())
... 
>>> o=template.render(vars=vars)
>>> print(o)


<div id=ac9a3707-3906-4e75-9efd-514959056ddb class="divTableRow">
  <div class="divTableCell">
    <input type="text" name=varname_ac9a3707-3906-4e75-9efd-514959056ddb value=kepada class="vTextField" maxlength="20" >
  </div>

  <div class="divTableCell">
    <input type="text" name=varlabel_ac9a3707-3906-4e75-9efd-514959056ddb value=Kepada class="vTextField" maxlength="20" >
  </div>

  <div class="divTableCell">
    <select name=vartype_ac9a3707-3906-4e75-9efd-514959056ddb>
      
        <option value=1>
      
      Integer</option>

      
        <option value=2 selected>
      
      String</option>

      
        <option value=3>
      
      Date</option>

    </select>
  </div>

  <div class="divTableCell">
    <input type="text" name=varformat_ac9a3707-3906-4e75-9efd-514959056ddb   class="vTextField" maxlength="20" >
  </div>
</div>

>>> 
>>>
```

got no error, and the output just like expected.
It's show there is no problem in jinja2 about integer comparison.

Kindly please tell me whats wrong with my views.py.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead:

```py
{% if v.vartype_value == 1 %}
    <option value=1 selected>
{% else %}
    <option value=1>
{% endif %}
```

Use it like `v.vartype_value == 1`, do proper spacing.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me,

```
{% if v.vartype_value == 1 %}
```

add spacess in between the condition